# Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType) return null using c#

Tags: c#, reflection

We have a requirement to load the dll dynamically. so i have used the Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType) c# code but it returning null.can you please help me

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippet?

Comment: Are you sure it returns null and doesn't throw?

Comment: Assuming that `assemblyType` is a `Type`: what type is it? Some types box to null in their default value form (think: `int?`, `YourStruct?`, etc)

Comment: We cannot help you with such a vague description. Please post some code of what you are doing. Preferably with a [mcve].

Comment: IProtocolPluginLibrary.IHTTPSProtocol plugin = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType) as IProtocolPluginLibrary.IHTTPSProtocol;

Comment: assemblyType is Type and it is not null,getting required class type but getting plugin is null while calling Activator.CreateInstance() method. It is not giving any error.please help me

Answer (score 1):

Normally if `CreateInstance` encounters a problem it throws. However if you look further down its [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_) we can spot:

> The method returns null for the Nullable instances.

---

I think you may be casting early and the types don't match:

```
   var o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(X));

   var x = o as X; // not null 

   var y = o as Y; // null
```